# How to compile/link Boost with clang++/libc++?

Tags: c++, boost, clang, libc++

The answer to this question [Why can't clang with libc++ in c++0x mode link this boost::program_options example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8454329/331024) states "You need to rebuild boost using clang++ -stdlib=libc++."

I'm using MacOS Lion with clang v3.0. How do I build Boost v1.48.0 using clang and link it with libc++?

Update: I've created a *user-config.jam* file with the following:

```
using clang-darwin
```

...which will build Boost with clang instead of gcc. How do I link with libc++ instead of libstdc++?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

I didn't know how to do this either.  But after poking around in [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/bbv2/overview.html#bbv2.overview.configuration), the [getting started](https://github.com/boostorg/boost/wiki/Getting-Started), and [trial](https://gist.github.com/Shauren/5c28f646bf7a28b470a8) and error:

```
$ ./bootstrap --with-toolset=clang
$ ./b2 clean
$ ./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"
```

You'll get lots of warnings.  And the signals library will fail to build due to [LWG 2059](http://lwg.github.com/issues/lwg-active.html#2059).  But otherwise I *think* it works.

Comment: Just to add, boost::signals2 (`#include <boost/signals2.hpp>`) has a similar API to boost::signal and is header only, so not being able to build signals may not be so bad.

Comment: Is it just boost::signal not getting built? I think I am missing a lot of variants when build complete

Comment: nevermind. i think the bootstrap for boost wasn't finding iconv for some reason and cause it not build some of my boost variant

Comment: This saved my day! It compiles fine with no warnings latest Boost 1.62 with Apple LLVM ver 7.0.2.

Comment: Note that depending on one's system, one might also need to explicitly use `update-alternatives` to configure aliases for `clang++` (otherwise `b2` can't find the proper toolset). The packages from [apt.llvm.org](http://apt.llvm.org) don't set these aliases automatically.

Comment: On Windows, the toolset is ```clang-win```

Answer (score 14):

Another option is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
brew install boost --c++11
```

To get information on all options use:

```
brew info boost
```

Comment: Does this link against `libc++` instead of `libstdc++`?

Comment: if clang is available it links with libc++.

Comment: I ran "brew install boost --c++11" followed by "otool -L /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.57.0/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib" and can confirm that Boost is now linking against libc++. Thanks!

Comment: Related lines in brew's boost formula - https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/c77a584/Library/Formula/boost.rb#L121-L126

Comment: Does this have `boost::mpl`?