# Multicast delegate/signals library that works with Clang and Boost 1.48?

Tags: c++, delegates, c++11, signals, clang

I have tried to use clang 3.0 with libc++ and C++0x.

I have compile the boost 1.48 with libc++, according to 
[How to compile/link Boost with clang++/libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486077/how-to-compile-link-boost-with-clang-libc)
The boost/signals is broken.

So, I am looking for a replacement of boost/signals, and the [Jae's Fast Delegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18389/Fast-C-Delegate-Boost-Function-drop-in-replacement) looks good, except it depends of an early version of boost.

```
#include <boost/pending/ct_if.hpp>
```

The file above was removed on 1.48.

So, is there an other candidate multi-cast delegate/signals works with clang 3.0 and C++0x?

Comment: Why are you trying to replace Boost.Signals? Shouldn't you be trying to get it to *work*?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. @NicolBolas According to http://lwg.github.com/issues/lwg-active.html#2059 It is almost impossible to fix.

Comment: @Logan: Why is adding a `static_cast<const_iterator>` to the calls to `erase` problematic?

Comment: @HowardHinnant According to the url, the const_iterator make some kind of ambiguousness. `This breaks code where the map's key_type has a constructor which accepts an iterator (for example a template constructor), as the compiler cannot choose between erase(const key_type&) and erase(const_iterator).`

Comment: @Logan:  Ah, sorry for the confusion.  That comment refers to a resolution of having the vendor supply both iterator and const_iterator overloads of erase.  If the client converts the iterator to a const_iterator at the point of calling erase, there is no ambiguity.  The code will just work.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Got it, and thank you. I'll try to fix the boost::signals later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace `boost::ct_if` with `boost::mpl::if_c` (and `#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>`) in Jae's Fast Delegate code.

Comment: I looked at Jae's code where it used ct_if, looked at the old definition of that in Boost, and I happened to know that Boost MPL has something very similar.  Fun fact: `<boost/detail/select_type.hpp>` is the actual "replacement" for ct_if, but I pointed you to the MPL version because it is more similar to ct_if, and is not a "detail" so not likely to go away anytime soon.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/signals2.html

Signals2 is header only, and included with boost. It has a few nice extra features like being thread-safe.

Edit:
Looks like there's a bug in the current version of signals2 that prevents it from working with clang. [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576112/implicit-instantiation-of-undefined-template-boost-bug-or-clang-bug) it'll be fixed in boost 1.50