# implicit instantiation of undefined template: Boost Bug or Clang Bug?

Tags: c++, boost, clang, shared-ptr

I was trying to compile some code that uses Boost (1.49), with Clang(& libc++) from trunk.
The problematic code boils down to the following:

```
#include <memory>
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> s;
}
```

When compiled with Clang, the following message is emmited:

```
$ clang++ -I/home/alexander/usr/local/include --stdlib=libc++ -std=c++0x signals2-bug.cpp   -o signals2-bug
signals2-bug.cpp:6:26: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::shared_ptr<int>'
    std::shared_ptr<int> s;
                         ^
/home/alexander/usr/local/include/boost/signals2/detail/foreign_ptr.hpp:24:30: note: 
      template is declared here
  template<typename T> class shared_ptr;
                         ^
```

The offending lines in boost/signals2/detail/foreign_ptr.hpp are:

```
#if !defined(BOOST_INTEL_STDCXX0X)
namespace std
{
  template<typename T> class shared_ptr;
  template<typename T> class weak_ptr;
}
#endif
```

Now who's to blame?

Two things come to mind:

1. Why does the Boost.Signals header feel the need to declare an own shared_ptr? What's the gain?
2. The line in Boost.Signals looks like a simple forward declaration. Why would that be problematic, if it comes after the template definition?

**EDIT**

This appears to be a Boost.Signals2 bug, because the declaration of things in the std:: namespace results in undefined behaviour, according to the ISO/IEC C++ 2011 Standard, section 17.6.4.2.1:

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or
>   definitions to namespace std or to a    namespace within namespace std
>   unless otherwise specified. A program may add a template
>   specialization
>       for any standard library template to namespace std only if the declaration depends on a user-defined type
>        and the specialization meets the standard library requirements for the original template and is not explicitly
>       prohibited.

A ticket in the Boost bug tracker has been created: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6655

Please note, that a Clang bug also exists here: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10521 , however the implementor points to violation.

**Follow-up for Googlers**:

The problem was indeed a Boost bug. This [changeset 77289](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/77289) should fix the issue for Boost 1.50.
The corresponding Bug in Clang was marked invalid.

Comment: What that looks like is a simple forward declaration that shouldn't confuse anyone. I'd rather think that by default CLang is not providing the tr1 `shared_ptr` in memory... Does your trivial `main` compile without the `<boost/signals2.hpp>` include?

Comment: Looks like a pretty clear bug in Boost.Signals2 to me.

Comment: @ildjarn: There shouldn't be a problem with *declaring* the templates, as long as the boost library doesn't attempt to *define* them. The error seems to say that there is no definition at all - apparently, including `<memory>` did not define `std::shared_ptr` as expected.

Comment: @Mike : Indeed, however the `#if` in the Boost code is clearly wrong (or at least less than ideal).

Comment: Yes, it does. Also, if i make the same declaration in the code myself, the compile fails with the same message, so it probably is a Clang bug.

Comment: There allready is a Clang bug: http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=10521 , but an implementor states that declaring something in std:: is results in undefined behaviour.

Comment: Have you posted this on the boost users forum: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/

Comment: @MikeSeymour There is a problem simply declaring the templates, because an implementation of the C++ library actually has a lot of leeway in declarations, and forward declarations would have to match the choices made by the implementation. In this case libc++ puts things in an inline namespace, so a correct forward declaration would have to do the same. Another example would be an implementation that adds defaulted extra parameters to a standard function. Ideally there'd be standard headers available to forward declare as much of the standard library as possible.

Comment: @mark: No, I didn't, bute the issue seems to have been fixed in [this revision](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/changeset/77289).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in `foreign_ptr.hpp` is a redeclaration (if `shared_ptr` has already been defined), and as such not likely to cause problems (adding declarations to `std` is technically undefined behavior, but most compilers don't care since they don't really distinguish between standard library headers and other files).  So the error can only be caused by `shared_ptr` being actually undefined.

Now `libc++` obviously has a definition `shared_ptr`, so I can only suspect some C++03 library made it to the include path somehow and got preferred over libc++.

Comment: Good Idea, but I checked the include paths (with the -v switch), and there is no other <memory> header before the one from libc++.

Comment: I think the key point is, that it is undefined behaviour! The standard mentions it in 17.6.4.2.1. I will edit to explain and report a Bug against Boost.Signals2.

Comment: This answer is not correct. The error is proximally caused by libc++ declaring shared_ptr in an inline namespace nested within std, and distally caused by the undefined behaviour of the boost code.