# Remove Boost libstdc++ dependency with clang++/libc++?

Tags: c++, boost, clang, libstdc++, libc++

The answer to this question [How to compile/link Boost with clang++/libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486077/how-to-compile-link-boost-with-clang-libc) states to build `Boost` with `clang++` and `libc++`, the following should do:

```
./b2 clean
./b2 toolset=clang cxxflags="-stdlib=libc++" linkflags="-stdlib=libc++"
```

I tested the above tip on a Scientific Linux 6.4 x86_64 host and it works "mostly" building the full Boost 1_53_0 distribution, with `clang++ 3.3sv` and `libc++ 3.3svn`. I said mostly, as I really like to remove all `libstdc++` dependency.

Nevertheless, the following:

- `libboost_graph`
- `libboost_locale`
- `libboost_regex`

still shows `libstdc++` dependencies (the `ldd` output makes it quite obvious).  I would like to know a good way to remove such and would appreciate any hint.

Comment: are you basically looking to statically link libstdc++? Or something else?

Comment: On Linux you may be linking to libstdc++ to get the low level libsupc++ support, but I am not sure of that theory.  There exist non-GPL replacements for this, search for libc++abi or libcxxabi.

Comment: @alrikai, Actually what I would like to do is to statically link libc++ so that I can run software implemented in C++11 on systems running older Linux, e.g. RHEL 5.x, 6.x.

Comment: @Howard Hinnant, Thanks for chipping in. I read about that on the libc++ Web site, but thought that I could skip it. OK, I will give it a try.

Comment: I took a closer look of `boost_1_53_0/libs/regex/build` a while ago while taking a short break from my daily work.  I saw a bunch `*.mak` files.  One of them is called `generic.mak`, the rest have names that have explicit association with specific compilers.  OK. I will tinker with the `generic.mak` a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @user183394, C++ code without the exact C++ libraries (and others) just won't work. Recompile for the environment where it will run, anything else is just screaming for trouble.

Comment: How can we get MacPorts to do this?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

I found out how to do it.  Thanks to @Howard Hinnant for his mentioning of `libc++abi`. After RTFM http://libcxx.llvm.org/, it's trivial to build the entire boost libraries free of any `libstdc++` dependencies. Yes, all I had to do is to RTFM!

Comment: Well, we are glad you found the solution, but a general answer of the kind of "RTFM" isn't actually helping those who need a little bit more help than others. Do you want to at least point in the right direction (specific, not general, link, a section to look at, etc)?

Comment: Yes, useless answer, -1