# Some problems when using Boost Library on Xcode

Tags: xcode, boost, c++11, g++, llvm

I use Xcode 4.5.2 and I wonna use Boost, but I got some problems.

In Build Setting, if I choose libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support), I will get the error messgae "Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error".
Just like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::filesystem::path_traits::dispatch(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >&, std::__1::codecvt<wchar_t, char, __mbstate_t> const&)"
referenced from:
  boost::filesystem::path::path<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>(boost::filesystem::directory_entry const&, boost::enable_if<boost::filesystem::path_traits::is_pathable<boost::decay<boost::filesystem::directory_entry>::type>, void>::type*) in test1 - inverted index.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I include these two headers:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
```

I also add these in Build Phases:

```
libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib
libboost_filesystem-mt.a
libboost_system-mt.dylib
libboost_system-mt.a
```

Code is here:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/operators.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <set>

using namespace boost::filesystem;
std::map<std::string, std::set<int>> invertedIndex;
std::map<std::string, int> number;

bool check_char(const char in)
{
    if((in>='A' && in<='Z') || (in>='a' && in<='z'))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int main() {
    int con = 0;
    std::string word;

    path root("/Users/tomhu/Desktop/pro/data/");
    std::string rootDirectory = root.native();
    recursive_directory_iterator iter(root);
    recursive_directory_iterator end;
    for (; iter != end; ++iter)
    {
        if(is_regular_file(*iter))
        {
            std::string filename;
            std::string directory(rootDirectory);
            filename = iter->path().filename().native();
            directory.append(filename);
            std::ifstream fileIn(directory.c_str());
            number[filename] = con;

            if(!fileIn)
            {
                std::cerr << "File doesn't exist!" << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }

            while(fileIn>>word)
            {
                long po = 0;
                if(!check_char(*(word.end()-1)))
                    word.pop_back();
                transform(word.begin(),word.end(),word.begin(),::tolower);
                if(word=="i")
                    word="I";
                invertedIndex[word].insert(con);
            }
        }        
    }
    std::cout << con << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

!!!!!!!!
If I choose libstdc++ (GUN C++ standard library) in "Build Setting", I won't get any error message about Boost, but I can't use anything in C++11 Standard.

How to solve these problems?

Comment: Why are you linking against both the static and dynamic libraries?

Comment: Because I don't know which will work......

Comment: Try static; drop the dynamic.

Comment: It still doesn't work.

Comment: And how did you build boost?  Are you sure it's built for 64-bit?

Comment: I use MacPorts to install Boost, so I don't know whether it's built for 64-bit.

Comment: From the command line: `file /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.a` will tell you (look for `[x86_64]` at the end).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't clang with libc++ in c++0x mode link this boost::program\_options example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Why can't clang with libc++ in c++0x mode link this boost::program_options example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp) - Howard gave an excellent answer what's going wrong there.

And here is how you can recompile Boost for clang+libc++: [How to compile/link Boost with clang++/libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486077/how-to-compile-link-boost-with-clang-libc)