# log4cxx and clang++: linker errors in project written in C++11

Tags: c++11, homebrew, clang++, log4cxx

I try to build C++11-project on OS X Lion (10.7.5) with `clang++`. All is fine, except one problem with `log4cxx`: after compiling I get these linker errors:

```
Linking CXX executable css.fcg
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "log4cxx::FileAppender::FileAppender(log4cxx::helpers::ObjectPtrT<log4cxx::Layout> const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::PatternLayout::PatternLayout(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Level::toLevel(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Logger::getLogger(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Logger::info(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Logger::warn(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Logger::debug(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Logger::error(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Logger::fatal(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
  "log4cxx::Logger::trace(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) const", referenced from:
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This is my `clang++`:

```
Apple LLVM version 4.2 (clang-425.0.27) (based on LLVM 3.2svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
```

I build project with flags `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libc++`. Attempting to build project with `Clang 3.2` didn't help.

Moreover, I've tried to install `log4cxx` library with `port` or with `brew` - same errors in both cases.

So what can I do?

Comment: Do you link with `-llog4cxx` ?

Comment: Of course. I use `cmake 3.0` and I set `log4cxx` as required lib, so I see in `Makefile`: `/usr/bin/cmake++ ... -lmp3lame -lmemcache -lz -lpthread -lfcgi -liconv -llog4cxx -Wl,-rpath,/opt/local/lib`. And I see that `log4cxx` exists in `/usr/local/lib` (after installing with `brew`).

Comment: I read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486077/how-to-compile-link-boost-with-clang-libc) and try to rebuild `log4cxx` like this: `brew uninstall log4cxx && brew install log4cxx --c++11`. It didn't help...

Comment: And this variant `brew install log4cxx --with-c++11` didn't help.

Comment: Maybe reason in incompatibility of `libstdc++` and `libc++`, so `log4cxx` must be compiled with `clang++` + `libc++` instead of `gcc` + `libstdc++`. Isn't it?

Comment: Try to `find` the libraries (`-name "*log4cxx*"`) and get the right path. They might have been installed somewhere else. 
On my Linux system, `pkg-config` says I need also `-lnsl` as linker flag.

Comment: I found `lib4cxx` in `/usr/local/lib`. In fact, `brew` makes a link: `~ $ liblog4cxx.dylib -> ../Cellar/log4cxx/0.10.0/lib/liblog4cxx.dylib`