# Possible reasons a library can't link for a specific architecture?

Tags: c++, ios, linker, static-libraries, crypto++

I've been pulling my hair out trying to link my iOS app with an arm64 library.

The library in question is Crypto++. I've tried both the precompiled fat library that's in the wiki : http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_(Command_Line). I've tried compiling the library myself, but I keep getting link errors of the following kind:

```
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__init(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in libcryptopp.a(randpool.o)
      std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > std::__1::operator+<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, char const*) in libcryptopp.a(modes.o)
```

The libcryptopp.a seems to be fine for armv7, but not for arm64 for some reason. If I exclude libcryptopp.a's 64 bit version from the linking process, it gives even more errors.

They both were compiled using -stdlib=libstdc++

What is going on?

(I need arm64 support because of tweak development reasons)

**update** sorry all - it turns out it was using the old libcryptopp.a, and not finding the libcryptopp.a properly. The .a was sourced from somewhere else, which has been fixed.

Comment: It's having problems finding the `+ operator` for concatenating strings in the `libc++` namespace.. you need to link against libc++. `-stdlib=libc++` NOT `-stdlib=libstdc++` I know it seems like a minor detail but it happens a lot more than it should.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames but the instructions say -stdlib=libstdc++, and wouldn't linking with libc++ cause errors when the library was compiled with libstdc++?

Comment: Aren't you building it? Perhaps you can also just link to it anyway and see what happens. For why to to use `-stdlib=libc++`:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352833/linking-with-clang-on-os-x-generates-lots-of-symbol-not-found-errors  and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000816/libc-stop-std-renaming-to-std-1

Answer (score 1):

> "std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::__init(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long)", referenced from: ... libcryptopp.a(randpool.o)

This library has been built, and depends on LLVM's C++ runtime `libc++`, and *not* GNU's C++ runtime `libstdc++`.

> They both were compiled using -stdlib=libstdc++

You need to *either* rebuild `libcryptopp.a` against `libstdc++`, *or* link with `-stdlib=libc++` (and build the rest of your code against `libc++` as well).

---

If interested, the `__1` is an inline namespace used for versioning. See [What are inline namespaces for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11016220) and [Where does the __1 symbol come from when using LLVM's libc++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29293394).

Comment: The wiki page cited provides one of the solutions under [Xcode Project](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_(Command_Line)#Xcode_Project).

Comment: Actually, I compiled the library myself, and made sure they use the -libstdc++, so that statement wasn't wrong. I did try earlier with the precompiled library which didn't work (I guess because it was linked with libc++)