# Can't compile program with gcc-4.9

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, g++4.9

I downloaded gcc-4.9 via homebrew. My original goal was to get openMP to work with some code I've written (c++).

But now I can't get any of my code to compile.

Here's my makefile:

```
 EXE := program
 CC := g++-4.9
 CFLAGS := -std=c++11 -Wall -m64

 program_C_SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp)
 program_C_OBJS := ${program_C_SRCS:.cpp=.o}
 all: $(EXE)

$(EXE ): $(program_C_OBJS)
     $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(program_C_OBJS) -o $(EXE)
clean:
     rm -f $(program_C_OBJS) $(EXE)
```

Here's the error.

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
 "std::__1::locale::has_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
   std::__1::basic_filebuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_filebuf() in matmult.o
  "std::__1::locale::use_facet(std::__1::locale::id&) const", referenced from:
  readInMatrix(double*, int, int, std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in matmult.o

 ...

 ...


ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [matmult] Error 1
```

Comment: `matmult.o` was compiled with clang and libc++ (the telltale sign is `std::__1`). Clean everything and rebuild.

Comment: Done. Get same error.

Comment: iostream,fstream,cstdlib

Comment: There should either be a lib64 directory under the root installation directory or an amd64 directory under the lib directory under the root installation directory. Cd to the directory that exists then do: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(pwd) with bash then try again

Comment: @Qwertyzw I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: So...let's start by figuring out where you installed your gcc..

Comment: /usr/bin/gcc and /usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9

Comment: I see...is there a /usr/lib64 ? Or /usr/lib/amd64

Comment: No. I don't see anything with a lib64 or amd64.

Comment: To me it looks like matmult ( usually a part of libm ) is trying to link against a version of libc++ that it cant find..looks a little similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000816/libc-stop-std-renaming-to-std-1 I may be wrong though