# Is clang's libc++ production ready?

Tags: c++, clang, libc++

Has anyone got a positive experience using clang's `libc++` in production? 
Status chart at http://libcxx.llvm.org/libcxx_by_chapter.pdf doesn't look very good to me.

Comment: AFAIK, that chart is extremely outdated.

Comment: @KennyTM, how to find out the latest status then?

Comment: libc++ on Apple's OS's is ready for prime time.  The chart you reference shows a few obscure localization tests failing.  If those tests were run against the libstdc++ shipping on Apple's OS's nearly all of the localization tests would fail.

Comment: It has come to my attention that the chart is easy to misinterpret to read (for example) that [thread] is not quite 5% complete.  My bad.  [thread] is 100% complete and composes not quite 5% of the entire library.  The chart made more sense when large parts of libc++ had yet to be implemented.  I've taken the chart down and replaced it with a statement that libc++ is 100% implemented on Apple's OS's.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using it on Mac OS for quite a while and never had any trouble with it. It's actually the default when you create a new Xcode project on Mac OS, and to my knowledge the only (reasonable) way of doing C++11 on a Mac since Apple probably won't update libstd++ any further.

I can't speak for Linux / Windows though, never tried that.

Something that you should keep in mind is that it's invasive, meaning if you want to use it in your project you have to link any dependency libraries against it too. That may or may not be a problem in your case.

Edit: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp) for details on the invasiveness.

Comment: "libg++" => "libstdc++".  Also it's not supported under 10.6 and below.