# Why are std::stoi and std::array not compiling with g++ c++11?

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, g++, std

I've been learning C++ and using the Terminal for the last couple of months. My code was compiling and running fine using g++ and C++11, but in the last couple of days it started giving errors and I have had problems compiling since. The only programs I can compile and run depend on older C++ standards.

The errors I first got related to `#include <array>` in the header file. Not sure why this happened, but I got around it by using `boost/array` instead. Another error I can't solve is with `std::stoi`. Both `array` and `stoi` should be in the C++11 standard library. I made the following simple code to demonstrate what's going on:

```
//
//  stoi_test.cpp
//
//  Created by ecg
//

#include <iostream>
#include <string> // stoi should be in here

int main() {

    std::string test = "12345";
    int myint = std::stoi(test); // using stoi, specifying in standard library
    std::cout << myint << '\n'; // printing the integer

    return(0);

}
```

Try to compile using `ecg$ g++ -o stoi_trial stoi_trial.cpp -std=c++11`

```
> array.cpp:13:22: error: no member named 'stoi' in namespace 'std'; did you mean
>      'atoi'?
>    int myint = std::stoi(test);
>                ~~~~~^~~~
>                     atoi
> /usr/include/stdlib.h:149:6: note: 'atoi' declared here
> int      atoi(const char *);
>         ^
> array.cpp:13:27: error: no viable conversion from 'std::string' (aka
>      'basic_string<char>') to 'const char *'
>    int myint = std::stoi(test);
>                          ^~~~
> /usr/include/stdlib.h:149:23: note: passing argument to parameter here
> int      atoi(const char *);
>                          ^
> 2 errors generated.
```

I also get these errors at compilation when using gcc or clang++ and with `-std=gnu++11` (I guess they all depend on the same file structure). I also get the same error whether I specify `std::` in the code, or if I specify `using namespace std;`

I worry that these issues arose because of the September Command Line Tools update via Xcode or because I installed boost and this somehow messed up my C++11 libraries. Hopefully there is a simple solution.

My system:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-> dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix
```

Thanks for any insight you can offer.

Comment: Try running gcc/clang -v, what do you get?
I know support on OSX is a bit behind the game when it comes to C++11, probably a bit behind this: http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain behind with gcc maybe, clang support is totally up to date though

Comment: Thanks for your comments. `ecg$ clang -v` gives 
`Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.75) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix` and `ecg$ gcc -v` gives
`Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.76) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.5.0
Thread model: posix` Does that look normal?

Comment: The semicolon after the closing `}` in `main` is superfluous (and, strictly speaking, illegal).

Comment: @user2865112 Clang looks up to date, GCC does not.

Comment: @KeithThompson I probably should have read the code first XD

Comment: @KeithThompson thanks for the tip, I've now removed the superfluous semicolon.

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain thanks for all your help. I am not sure that updating gcc will solve my problem. Why do recent g++ and clang not work?

Comment: Ah I see, g++ is dependent on gcc (and presumably clang is too). I updated gcc and the error has gone away. Thanks @TheFloatingBrain, you truly are brainy :-) I don't know how this problem arose with my C++11 dependent code this week - using `port select --list gcc`
Available versions for gcc:
 llvm-gcc42
 mp-gcc47    shows only two versions on my system so it's not like it reverted to an alternative older version before my update tonight. Anyway I'm happy to now be working error free.

Answer (score 5):

clang has a weird stdlib, you need to add the following flag when you compile

`-stdlib=libc++`

your snippet works on my mac with

`g++ -std=gnu++11  -stdlib=libc++ test.cpp -o test`

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459894/clang-stdlib-libc-leads-to-undefined-reference/18460312#18460312) describes the problem