# Undefined symbol in shared object file

Tags: c++, templates, g++, undefined-reference

I compiled my code using:

```
gcc -c -O3 -fPIC -fno-rtti -fno-implicit-templates -Wno-deprecated -I. -I/rw/include/ Exotic.C -o RBCExotic.o
```

When I try to use the 'RBCExotic.o' file, I get the error below.

```
loading error /home/rw/rw_lib/Exotics.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5ArrayIPKvE4sizeEibbb
```

When I demangled the code using nm, the line that was giving me an error was this:

```
U Array<void const*>::size(int, bool, bool, bool)
```

However, this 'size' function is defined and implemented in a header file within '/rw/include/' as such:

```
template <class T>
int
Array<T>::size(int n, bool reduceMem, bool copyData, bool delData)
{
    return _size(n, reduceMem, copyData, delData);
}
```

And '_size' is also defined right below it.

Am I compiling this code incorrectly? Are there any other possible issues where this could be some sort of red herring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-fno-implicit-templates` means "do not instantiate the templates I use, I will do so manually by providing explicit instantiations."

So you have lied to the compiler. You told it not to bother instantiating the `Array<T>::size` function template in order to provide the required symbol, so it did what you asked, but you didn't keep your end of the bargain.

The best solution is to stop using that option, and let the compiler Do The Right Thing automatically. When you use `Array<void const*>::size(int, bool, bool, bool)` it will instantiate the generic definition in the header file and provide the missing symbol.

See the [GCC manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Template-Instantiation.html) for more information, although that page is very out of date and the bit saying `-frepo` is the best option should be ignored. The best option is the third one.

If you really, really want to use that option, you need to provide an explicit instantiation for every template you use (which is the second option in the GCC docs). In a `.C` file (not a header) define an explicit instantiation of `Array<void const*>` like so:

```
template class Array<void const*>;
```

Or for a single function:

```
template int Array<void const*>::size(int, bool, bool, bool);
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you including the header files (-I). Is that a Mac? I don't recognize the paths.
Maybe this can help you:

[clang++ -stdlib=libc++ leads to undefined reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18459894/clang-stdlib-libc-leads-to-undefined-reference/18460312#18460312)

I've seen the

```
g++ -std=c++11 your_file.cpp -o your_program -I(as necessary)
```

used elsewhere.