# -std=c++ 98 and OS X 10.10

Tags: c++, macos, g++, osx-yosemite, clang++

I'm currently trying to compiling my program with the -std=c++98 flag on OS X 10.10:

`clang++ -std=c++98 -pedantic -W -Wall -Werror *.cpp`

`g++ -std=c++98 -pedantic -W -Wall -Werror *.cpp`

Strangely when I compile with OS 10.10 no error are showed while some are showed with a GNU/Linux distribution.

With the GNU/Linux distribution I have some errors because I use `s.open(file);` instead of `s.open(file.c_str());` but on OS X no error, even by using `s.open(file);`.

Maybe there is just a link between this error and the filesystem of each OS?

Comment: What do you mean by "some" errors? Could you add an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct. This code shouldn't compile under C++98:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string file("/tmp/foo.txt");
    std::ifstream s;
    s.open(file);
}
```

It's technically a bug in libc++, but it's one that I doubt that they will want to fix.

If you wanted, you could compile with libstdc++ as the standard library, which doesn't have this feature implemented (at least the version that apple distributes doesn't).

```
[10:13am][wlynch@watermelon /tmp] clang++ -std=c++98 -stdlib=libstdc++ foo.cc
foo.cc:7:12: error: no viable conversion from 'std::string' (aka 'basic_string<char>') to 'const char *'
    s.open(file);
           ^~~~
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/fstream:518:24: note: passing argument to parameter '__s' here
      open(const char* __s, ios_base::openmode __mode = ios_base::in)
                       ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Perfect. So I just need to add the ```-stdlib=libstdc++``` flag to have the same errors as GNU/Linux.

Comment: Note that using libstdc++ in your program can have issues if you attempt to link with libraries provided by apple. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634803/link-different-c-standard-libraries-on-mac-os-x

Comment: "It's technically a bug in libc++" It's not a bug in libc++, it's simply that libc++ does not implement c++98.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that on OS X you're still using a C++11 implementation of the standard library, which includes such API changes as the `ostream::open` method accepting `std::strings`.

Changing the C++ standard with `-std=c++98` does not affect the standard library being used, and libc++ does not implement C++98 (e.g., there's no #ifdef to remove those `open(std::string)` APIs when in C++98 mode) whereas I think libstdc++ does hide non-c++98 APIs when building in C++98 mode.