# Why should I link GNU C++ Standard Library (libstdc++) when invoking opencv library on mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opencv

In many cases invoking opencv library also needs to invoke GNU C++ Standard Library (libstd++) on mac as [this post](http://www.theworldneedsmoredreamers.net/using-opencv-2-with-os-x-hello-world/) shows. Probably this is because the compiled opencv library need the support of GNU libstd++. However, as [this pos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634803/link-different-c-standard-libraries-on-mac-os-x)t shows, LLVM C++ Standard Library (libc++) is more promising in the future. Therefore, I decide to compile the opencv library from the source code and make a library that does not rely on libstd++ but rather it needs libc++.

The opencv library I am using is 2.4.8, and I build the static OPENCV library. The cmake script in opencv that is related to stdc++ is

```
set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS} stdc++)
```

, which is in OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake file. In order to make sure that opencv will not use libstd++ but libc++, I changed it to

```
set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS} c++)
```

When a Xcode was built with CMake, I also check the `CMakeCache.txt` file, which contains the link options for the project. I can clearly observe that libstd++ is not needed any more. For example, the `opencv_core` library:

```
//Dependencies for the target
opencv_core_LIB_DEPENDS:STATIC=general;zlib;general;c++;
```

However, when I invoke the opencv library from an application, it seems that libstd++ must be invoked in the meantime, otherwise I have the following error messages:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::size() const", referenced from:
      cv::fromUtf16(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
  "std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::c_str() const", referenced from:
      cv::fromUtf16(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
  "std::string::size() const", referenced from:
      cv::Exception::formatMessage() in libopencv_core.a(system.o)
      cv::error(cv::Exception const&) in libopencv_core.a(system.o)
      cv::tempfile(char const*) in libopencv_core.a(system.o)
      cv::FileStorage::getDefaultObjectName(std::string const&) in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
      cv::toUtf16(std::string const&) in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
      cv::operator<<(cv::FileStorage&, std::string const&) in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
      cv::write(cv::FileStorage&, std::string const&, std::string const&) in libopencv_core.a(persistence.o)
      ...
  "std::string::c_str() const", referenced from:
```

Any ideas on how to prepare the opencv library so that the libstd++ is not needed? Thanks.

**EDIT**:

I tried to let opencv picks up the native one by using the following cmake command:

```
 set(OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS})
```

However, it seems that opencv always picks up libstd++.

Comment: Why not remove the linking to a specific standard library completely, and let the build environment pick the "native" instead (i.e `libstdc++` when building with the GNU toolchain and `libc++` when building with Clang/Xcode)?

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks, and I have done that, but it seems the opencv always pick up the libstd++, and this is why I tried to force linking with libc++.

Comment: `export CXX='clang++ -stdlib=libc++` maybe?