# homebrew not installing JAGS

Tags: r, homebrew, jags, rjags

I'm trying to install JAGS through homebrew so I can use it in R. I am getting the following warning every time I install:

```
Warning: jags dependency gcc was built with a different C++ standard
library (libstdc++ from clang). This may cause problems at runtime.
```

Then, when I try to install `rjags` in R, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: "cannot link to JAGS library in /usr/local/Cellar/jags/4.3.0_2/lib."
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rjags’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.0/site-library/rjags’
```

I also tried following the installation guide in the JAGS 4.3.0 readme. This yielded the same error once I moved to R.

Googling leads me to the following links, none of which seem closely related enough to help me:

https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/4904
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/32112
[Link different C++ standard libraries on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19634803/link-different-c-standard-libraries-on-mac-os-x)

Here also is the entire result of my `brew doctor`

```
(base) aridf@Aris-MacBook-Pro ~ % brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/icu-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/krb5-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/freetype-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/xslt-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/libpng16-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/libpng-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/xml2-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/curl-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/ncursesw6-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/pcre-config
  /Users/aridf/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.8-config

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libtk8.6.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed header files were found in /usr/local/include.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected header files:
  /usr/local/include/fakemysql.h
  /usr/local/include/fakepq.h
  /usr/local/include/fakesql.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl.h
  /usr/local/include/itcl2TclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/itclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclInt.h
  /usr/local/include/itclIntDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/itclMigrate2TclCore.h
  /usr/local/include/itclTclIntStubsFcn.h
  /usr/local/include/mysqlStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/odbcStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/pqStubs.h
  /usr/local/include/tcl.h
  /usr/local/include/tclDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOO.h
  /usr/local/include/tclOODecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclPlatDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tclThread.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMath.h
  /usr/local/include/tclTomMathDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbc.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tdbcInt.h
  /usr/local/include/tk.h
  /usr/local/include/tkDecls.h
  /usr/local/include/tkPlatDecls.h

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tcl.pc
  /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/tk.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
  /usr/local/lib/libtclstub8.6.a
  /usr/local/lib/libtkstub8.6.a
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution, per https://gist.github.com/casallas/8411082, was to change `~/.R/Makedir` to the following:

```
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
```

Then reinstall the package in R