# Can inline namespaces be used to keep backwards compatibility in a shared library?

Tags: c++, c++11, abi, binary-compatibility

The rationale for C++'s inline namespaces is both source and binary compatibility (see Herb Sutter's paper linked in [N2535](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2535.htm)), but I have not been able to find good examples of *keeping* binary compatibility for existing libraries when introducing inline namespaces, or if it is possible.

(for more info, and examples of source compatibility, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11016220/what-are-inline-namespaces-for))

(for solving a related problem, using inline namespace to introduce incompability, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp/8457799#8457799))

If this is our current library (e.g. mylib.dll), which is shared with clients and need to be stable:

```
struct ModelA
{
   /* (...) lots of stuff */
};

struct ModelB
{
   /* (...) lots of stuff */
};
```

Can we use inline namespaces to introduce new versions of the structs/classes without breaking the clients (i.e. replace the shared library file (mylib.dll) only, no recompile neccessary)?

```
inline namespace mylib
{

inline namespace v1
{
struct ModelA
{
   /* (...) lots of stuff */
};
} // end namespace v1

namespace v2
{
struct ModelA
{
   /* (...) lots of stuff + newstuff */
};
} // end namespace v2

struct ModelB
{
   /* (...) lots of stuff */
};

} // end namespace mylib
```

If not, will it work without the enclosing inline namespace mylib?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really an answer to your question, but probably can lead to an answer.

Tested under `gcc 4.8.2` with two simple sources:

```
namespace n1
{
   void f1 (int);

   inline namespace n2
   {
      void f2 (int);
   }
}

void f (int x)
{
   n1::f1(x);
   n1::f2(x);
}
```

And without inline namespace:

```
namespace n1
{
   void f1 (int);
   void f2 (int);
}

void f (int x)
{
   n1::f1(x);
   n1::f2(x);
}
```

Then inspected mangled names of symbols in compiled object files using `objdump -t`.

Results for the first version (*with* inline namespace):

```
_ZN2n12f1Ei
_ZN2n12n22f2Ei
```

Second version (*without* inline namespace):

```
_ZN2n12f1Ei
_ZN2n12f2Ei
```

You can see that the mangled name of `f2` differs (the first one includes the name of `n2` namespace). It means that in case you are using `gcc`, you cannot just replace your library with a new one with inlined namespaces. I won't expect that some other compiler will do it another way (save binary compatibility with inline namespaces).

Comment: This suggests the answer to the question is "yes", provided you use inline namespaces all along (starting with version 1).