# How can I know the kind of C++ standard library that a static library or object file has invoked in MAC?

Tags: c++, macos

In MAC there are two different kinds of C++ standard libraries: libstdc++ and libc++, and mixing them can have link errors as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454329/why-cant-clang-with-libc-in-c0x-mode-link-this-boostprogram-options-examp) shows. So before I decide to use C++ standard library, I will first check the C++ standard library employed by the external library I will use. If the external library is dynamic library, I can use `otool -L` to check the standard library that it has invoked. Then my question is: what if the library is static library? Can I analyze the object file to get some ideas of its employed standard library?

Comment: Try to link it to libstdc++, if that fails try libc++.